# 1064 syntax error in mysql when creating a table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, create-table

```
drop table member cascade constraints;
create table member (
    mid varchar2(10) not null,
    email varchar2(40) not null,
    fname varchar2(20) not null,
    lname varchar2(20) not null,
    street varchar2(50) not null,
    city varchar2(30) not null,
    state varchar2(20) not null,
    zip number(5) not null,
    phone varchar2(12),
    password varchar2(20),
    primary key (mid)
);
```

Comment: I see DDL, but no question... Please take some time to frame your question as an actual question (not just a code dump). It helps us answer your question, and you may find the answer yourself in the process. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 5):

Well, cutting and pasting from Oracle doesn't always turn out well;

`VARCHAR2` doesn't exist as a datatype in MySQL.
`NUMBER` doesn't either.
`CASCADE CONSTRAINTS` doesn't seem to work as a modifier to `DROP TABLE` either.

As a replacement for `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`, you can drop multiple tables with one statement using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a,b,c`. Not quite the same, but as good as it gets.

What you want is probably something like;

```
drop table if exists member;

create table member (
  mid varchar(10) not null,
  email varchar(40) not null,
  fname varchar(20) not null,
  lname varchar(20) not null,
  street varchar(50) not null,
  city varchar(30) not null,
  state varchar(20) not null,
  zip numeric(5) not null,
  phone varchar(12),
  password varchar(20),
  primary key (mid)
);
```

[SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09805).

Comment: create table item (
ino numeric(5),
title varchar(128) not null,
category varchar(120) not null,
description varchar(2000),
openDateTime date,
sellerId varchar(10) not null,
startingBid numeric(7,2) not null,
bidIncrement number(7,2) not null,
closeDateTime Date,
winnerId varchar(10),
primary key (ino),
foreign key (category) references category,
foreign key (sellerId) references member,
foreign key (winnerId) references member
);

Comment: Well, cutting and pasting from Oracle doesn't always turn out well---Nice :)

Comment: @WailDrouiche Then use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item,member` to drop both tables at once.

Comment: i tryed to right, ino numeric(5) and after primary key(ino) but i got a syntax error

Comment: @WailDrouiche I'm not sure I understand what you mean, `ino` isn't a field in the table you're asking about, are you having trouble with more tables than this one? If it's about the table in the comment, `bidIncrement` is still `NUMBER`, not `NUMERIC`.

Comment: yep, it's another table... i'am trying to create a DB for an Online Auction service (an assignment to do ) using Mysql

Comment: @WailDrouiche Your second table still has bidIncrement as `NUMBER` and foreign keys need `REFERENCES member(mid)`. If you have more questions, they're better asked in a new SO question instead of comments.